# send parameter in event souce url every click on list item

Tags: javascript, php, eventsource

i have list items which every one has an id and when click on any list it's id will 
go to event source in url parameter

my code  :-

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-menu .online ul li',function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var allmessages = ''; 
    allmessages = new EventSource("/ajaxpages/insertmessage.php?id="+$(this).attr('id')+"");

    allmessages.onmessage = function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        $(".message .message-content").html(data);
    };
});
```

but i found that event source loop on all list item's id so how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're nesting event handlers. Declare `allmessages` outside of the first event handler, then redefine it inside:

```
var allmessages = "";

$(document).on('click','.navbar-menu .online ul li',function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    allmessages = new EventSource("/ajaxpages/insertmessage.php?id="+$(this).attr('id')+"");
});

allmessages.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    $(".message .message-content").html(data);
};
```

Comment: browser tell me that Cannot create property 'onmessage' on string so when i console.log(allmessages);  i found it null